# Grabbing the octet stream data from a Graph API response

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I have been working on some code to download a days worth of Teams usage data from the Graph API. I can successfully send the token and receive the response. The response apparently contains the URL in the head to download the csv file. I can't see to find the code to grab it though.

My code as the moment is as follows.

```
import requests, urllib, json, csv, os

client_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus('XXXX')
client_secret = urllib.parse.quote_plus('XXXX')
tenant = urllib.parse.quote_plus('XXXX')
auth_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant \
+ '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
auth_body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + client_id \
+ '&client_secret=' + client_secret \
+ '&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'
authorization = requests.post(auth_uri, data=auth_body, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
token = json.loads(authorization.content)['access_token']

graph_uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(date=2023-01-22)'
response = requests.get(graph_uri, data=auth_body, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})

print(response. Headers)
```

Is there any easy way to parse the URL from the header and to obtain the CSV file?

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

`response.headers` is a case-insensitive dictionary of response headers, so you should be able to get location header this way

```
locationUrl = response.headers['location']

# retrieving data from the URL using get method
response = requests.get(locationUrl)

# write response content to a file
with open("data.csv", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```